# What is the best way to use same docker service in several docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In SOA application I have several microservices. Each of it has its own git repository and own docker-compose.yml
Some services, like elasticsearch and rabbitmq should be shareable among all docker-compose.yml. How to do it the best way?
There is no problem when all microservices is running, but the problem exists if you want to work not with all microservices at one time.

Comment: Did you look at option of using docker swarm ? You also publish services like rabbitmq and EL to the host machine and use them directly using the host IP. Thats what we used to do for EL

Answer (score 0):

Services defined in multiple compose files can share a [external network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#using-a-pre-existing-network). You have to define the network on your host or swarm manager and then reference that network from the other compose files. Then you can access a service by servicename and port such as: http://elasticsearch:5601/somePath

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

However usually one would write one compose file for all microservices of an application because it is handyer to manage (you remove/start all services with one command, don't have to manage networks and so forth)